# Erro ao tentar inserir embed do gist (GitHub) via PHP

Tags: php, github

Estou a tentar inserir um embed de um gist via PHP da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
    echo "<script src='https://gist.github.com/schacon/4277.js'></script>";
?>
```

Porém, ao analisar o console, o seguinte erro é retornado:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.

Já tentei também:

```
echo "<iframe src='https://gist.github.com/schacon/4277.js'></iframe>";
```

e:

```
echo "<embed src='https://gist.github.com/schacon/4277.js'></embed>";
```

porém ambos retornam:

> Refused to display 'https://gist.github.com/schacon/4277.js' in a
>   frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Como posso fazer para ele mostrar o gist? Ou isso não é possível dessa maneira?